# Loopback "params" for running native SQL queries

Tags: node.js, postgresql, loopbackjs

Anybody know what "params" is/are for the Loopback docs here:

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Executing+native+SQL

it says:

**Executing native SQL**

To execute SQL directly against your data-connected model, use the following:

```
dataSource.connector.execute(sql, params, cb);
```

or

```
dataSource.connector.query(sql, params, cb); // For 1.x connectors
```

Where:
sql - The SQL string.
params - parameters to the SQL statement.
cb - callback function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is an array of values of your SQL string params. For example if you have postgresql database and parametrized query like this:

```
select * from table where id = $1 or name = $2
```

then you have to provide parameter values to your function, so you will do something like this:

```
var query = "select * from table where id = $1 or name = $2";
var params = [82, "My name"];
ds.connector.execute(query, params, function(err, data){
  if(err){
    console.log( err);
  }else{
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: AZ is one of my fav rappers btw :)

Comment: How about MS SQL ? i tried both ? and $1 also doesn't work.

Comment: MS SQL uses @param1 instead of $1